# Getting syntax error "Unexpected token var"

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

I'm creating an app for Android that evaluates a bit of javascript on a website in order to extract some data from it (I know it's not the best practice, but I'm kinda forced to)

This is the code (don't mind the Dutch):

```
(function get() {
    var rapporten = [];
    var rapportLength = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody").length;
    for ( r = 0; r < rapportLength; r++) {
        var rapport = {
            rapport : r
        };
        var vakken = [];
        var vakkenLength = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[r].children.length;
        for ( v = 0; v < vakkenLength; v++) {
            var vak = {};
            vak.naam = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[r].children[v].children[0].innerHTML;
            vak.heeftCijfers = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[r].children[v].children[1].children.length != 0;
            if (vak.heeftCijfers) {
                var cijfers = [];
                var cijfersLength = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[r].children[v].children[1].children.length;
                for ( c = 0; c < cijfersLength; c++) {
                    var cijfer = {};
                    cijfer.waarde = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[r].children[v].children[1].children[c].children[0].children[0].innerHTML;
                    cijfer.detailHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[r].children[v].children[1].children[c].children[0].rel;
                    cijfers.push(cijfer);
                }
                vak.cijfers = cijfers;
            }
            vakken.push(vak);
        }
        rapport.vakken = vakken;
        rapporten.push(rapport);
    }
    return rapporten;
})();
```

In the Google Chrome console it runs fine and returns what I need, but as soon as I evaluate it in an Android webview it throws the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var (1:link_to_website)
```

I'm running this on Android 4.4, the app is build in Titanium Studio. (Titanium converts to native so that shouldn't be the problem)

Comment: did you write it inside a script tag?

Comment: I think the problem with the code closer to the WebView creation, rather than the content of the url for the WebView.  Can you post that code as well?